# Connecting to MS Access 2007 using ODBC_CONNECT - error in driver?

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc, driver

I have been successful in querying a Microsoft Access 2003 database (.mdb file) and now I am trying to do the same for a Microsft Access 2007. I have tried the following:

```
if($type[1]=='accdb'){
    echo 'accdb';
    //2007 Microsoft Access 
    $connection = odbc_connect("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$mdbFilename;Persist Security Info=False;", $username, $password);

}else{
    echo 'mdb';
    //2000, 2003 Microsoft Access
    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $username, $password);

}
```

However, for an access 2007 database I get this error:

```
Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
 Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002in SQLConnect 
in E:\export.php on line 38
```

Comment: This is just a path to my database which changes from C:\Users\A\Documents\tester_07.accdb to C:\Users\A\Documents\tester.mdb.

Comment: Were you asking in case my path had spaces in it.

Comment: The ACE is backward-compatible, so there's no reason you need to use Jet 4 for older data (i.e., MDB), unless it's *really* old, like Jet 2.x or 3.x (and ACE may be able to deal with Jet 3.x -- I'm not sure and don't want to take the time to re-register A2007).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering how to do this. This worked for me.

```
try{
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $username, $password);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IKIK This is uber grave digging but..

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" . $mdbFilename, $username, $password);
```

This should work.

Comment: Why to post the same answer as the accepted one, and with a worse code than in the accepted one?