# How can i read data from .accdb access using php?(windows & linux)

Tags: php, windows, ms-access, ubuntu-server

I have an Ubuntu server. It runs Apache, Mysql, PHP. I develop on windows using Xampp and copy files into Ubuntu server. I need to use same code for Windows & Linux to read an Ms-access .accdb file using PHP.
Is there any solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to MS Access 2007 using ODBC_CONNECT - error in driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222684/connecting-to-ms-access-2007-using-odbc-connect-error-in-driver)

Comment: Have you considered using mysql instead?

Comment: I need to read Ms-access file to write it`s data into Mysql db.

Comment: Can i use ODBC_CONNECT in linux?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is no good solution for that.

The only library can handle Access file is [mdbtools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/), and it does not support accdb file(2007 version)